# How to extract a specific folder's name in PHP?

Tags: php

Say I have this:

```
folder-one/folder-2/folder-3/myfile.php
```

How would I be able to find the name of "folder-2"?
I know that if I use  `basename(__DIR__)` I will get 'folder-3' but I really need to find folder-2 and folder-one?

Comment: Use `explode` with `/` as the separator and `__DIR__` as the string.

Comment: What do you mean with `able to find` ?

Comment: I need to return the folder name so that I can store it in a variable and use it for a query afterwards

Comment: I would replace the word `find` with `extract` in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) with [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

If `__DIR__` is 'folder-one/folder-2/folder-3', then you can just use:

```
$dir = basename( dirname( __DIR__ ) );
```

Comment: You can also chain dirnames to get to higher levels e.g. `basename(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)))` will get folder-one

Answer (score 0):

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

Then explode etc etc.

[php.net dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)